# Android App Permissions Not Working Correctly

Tags: android, permissions

**Are there any specific steps required when configuring permissions for apps deployed through the Play Store?**

Only "write_external_storage" is specified and works as expected when built and run locally on a phone.  However, when installed from the Play Store there is no verification prompt for permission(s).

I have decompiled the .apk to verify that the permission exists in the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:"<a href="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
target="_blank" 
rel="nofollow">http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android</a>" 
android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" 
package="processing.test.hex_droid" platformBuildVersionCode="21" 
platformBuildVersionName="5.0.1-1624448">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
<application android:label="hex_droid" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:debuggable="false">
    <activity android:theme="@*android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: You need to code of User Permissions at run time.

Comment: No he doesn't , this is highest version 21. Only 23 and up require Runtime Permissions

Comment: Why is this getting downvoted? Is this a bad question?

Comment: Probably b/c your question run's on a bit. Be succinct and straight to the point, clearly asking your question and presenting any related info.

Comment: Did you check what permissions are listed under Settings->Apps->App->Permissions ?

Comment: Asking "how do i" questions are frowned upon as well, they're too general.

Comment: Did you try other permissions to rule out that it's not a storage specific issue?

Comment: When installed from the phone it shows permissions listed in the app manager. From the store it shows no special permissions in app manager.

Comment: I have not tried other permissions yet. I suppose I could create a branch and run a small alpha test from the console.

Comment: Is the "local" app and store app built with same config (Debug/Release)?

Comment: You could try lowering android:targetSdkVersion (start with 15 and go up).

Answer (score 0):

According to these [**Storage Options**](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) docs:

> **Saving files that are app-private**
>
> Beginning with Android 4.4, reading or writing files in your app's
> private directories does not require the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE or
> WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permissions. So you can declare the permission
> should be requested only on the lower versions of Android by adding
> the maxSdkVersion attribute:

```
<manifest ...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
                     android:maxSdkVersion="18" />
    ...
</manifest>
```